# qsort in C: compare Strings

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

I have following question:
My compare function in qsort looks like this:

```
static int compare(const void *arg1, const void *arg2) {
    return strcmp((const char *) arg1, (const char *) arg2);
}
```

This did not work, so I looked up the code example in the man page and I changed it a little bit, so now it looks like this:

```
static int compare(const void *arg1, const void *arg2) {
    return strcmp( *(char * const *) arg1, *(char * const *) arg2);
}
```

I don't get it why the method of the man page works, because the parameter of strcmp are const char *s1 and const char *s2.

I am pretty new to C, so I find it difficult to understand this. Can someone please explain this to me why only the method of the man pages works.

Comment: Please look for the duplicates — there are many similar questions already answered.  Options include (in no order of merit): [SO 14993282](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993282/), [SO 5035289](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035289/), [SO 18400333](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400333/), [SO 19558447](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558447/). I'm sure there are others too.  Try searching with `[c] qsort string` in the SO search box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The succinct answer to your question is that the pointers passed to the comparison function are not `char *` but `char **`.

If you think about it, if you were sorting an array of integers, you'd be passed two `int *` values (disguised as `void *`). If you are sorting an array of doubles, you'd be passed two `double *` values; if you are sorting an array of strings, you are passed two pointers to strings, which means two `char **` values.

Comment: Really succinct and precise.

Answer (score 3):

`man qsort` says:

> The contents of the array are sorted in ascending order according to a comparison function
>   pointed to by `compar`, which is called with two arguments that point to the objects being compared.

It's clear that "with two arguments that point to the objects being compare". So when comparing two `char *` strings, the argument are in type "pointers to pointers to `char`", which is also covered in the manpage:

```
   static int
   cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
   {
       /* The actual arguments to this function are "pointers to
          pointers to char", but strcmp(3) arguments are "pointers
          to char", hence the following cast plus dereference */

       return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
   }
```

And `man strcmp` will tell you that its prototype is:

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

where the arguments are "pointers to `char`".

Therefore the conversion solves this.

You may need to read the manpage carefully.